# Prove $\log(n!) =\Omega(n\log(n))$

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics

Can someone help me prove that $\log(n!) =\Omega(n\log(n))$, that is, that there exists some positive $c$ such that, for every $n$ large enough, $\log (n!)\geqslant c\cdot n\cdot \log(n)$?

Comment: There is no constant with $\log n! = c n \log n$ (unless you're referring to a specific value of $n$, in which case it's trivial). Also, what is $x$?

Comment: For each $n$, take $c=\frac {\ln n!}{n\ln n}$ :-P.

Comment: @anomaly: please see edit

Comment: Is the sentence "In other words" supposed to mean that you ask how to prove that there exists some positive $c$ such that $\log(n!) \geqslant c\cdot n\cdot \log(n)$ for every $n$ large enough?

Comment: I rewrote the question accordingly. Now, the big missing part, that only you can add, is what you tried to solve this... If you do not add ithis part, the question might get closed, justifiably so.

Comment: Reading the posts below, I feel I might point out that Stirling is quite unnecessary to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose
$\ln(n!)
\ge cn\ln(n)
$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
\ln((n+1)!)
&=\ln(n!)+\ln(n+1)\\
&\ge cn\ln(n)+\ln(n+1)\\
\text{and this is}
&\ge c(n+1)\ln(n+1)\\
\text{if}\\
cn\ln(n)+\ln(n+1)
&\ge c(n+1)\ln(n+1)\\
&= cn\ln(n+1)+c\ln(n+1)\\
&= cn(\ln(n)+\ln(1+1/n))+c\ln(n+1)\\
\text{or}\\
\ln(n+1)
&\ge cn\ln(1+1/n)+c\ln(n+1)\\
\text{or}\\
(1-c)\ln(n+1)
&\ge cn\ln(1+1/n)\\
\text{but}\\
\ln(1+1/n)
&< 1/n\\
\text{so this is true if}\\
(1-c)\ln(n+1)
&\ge c\\
\text{or}\\
\ln(n+1)
&\ge \frac{c}{1-c}\\
\end{array}
$

and this is true
for any $c$
between $0$ and $0$
for
$n
\ge e^{c/(1-c)}-1
$.

To initialize,
choose a $c \in (0, 1)$,
get 
$n
\ge e^{c/(1-c)}-1
$,
and see if
$\ln(n!)
\ge cn\ln(n)
$.
$c = .6$
works for
$n \ge 10$.

Comment: And what about the initialization?

Comment: I added explanation at the end.

Answer (score 6):

For a lower bound, note that 
$$(n!)^2=[1\cdot n][2\cdot (n-1)][3\cdot (n-2)]\cdots [(n-1)\cdot 2][n\cdot 1].$$
For any $k$ between $1$ and $n$, we have $k(n+1-k)\ge n$. It follows that
$$(n!)^2\ge n^n,$$
and therefore
$$\log(n!) \ge \frac{1}{2}n\log n.$$

Answer (score 3):

It's not. You might use Stirling's approximation
$$
\log n! = n\log n-n+O(\log n)
$$
to achieve your goal.

Comment: Can you please explain this more?

Comment: @MATH000 : I don't understand what Henrik says, this shows that $\log n! \sim n \log n$

Answer (score 1):

The  natural logaritm is a strictly  increasing function, so for $2\leq n\in N$ we have $$\int_{n-1}^n \log x\;dx<\log n<\int_n^{n+1} \log x\;dx.$$ Therefore, for $2\leq n\in N,$we have $$n\log n -n=\int_1^n\log x \;dx<\sum_{j=2}^n\log j=\log n!$$ And for $3\leq n\in N$ we have $$\log n!=\log n+\sum _{j=2}^{n-1}\log j<\log n +\int_2^n\log x \;dx=$$ $$=(n+1)\log n-n-(2 \log 2-2).$$  Since  $[n\log n-n]/n\log n\;$ and $\;[(n+1)\log n-n-(2\log 2-2)]/n\log n\;$ both converge to $1$ as $n\to \infty,$ the inequalities imply $$\lim_{n\to \infty}(n \log n)/\log n!=1.$$